# android - disable background data

Tags: android, android-manifest

In Android phones users can restrict an app and disallow any background data.

In our app we are using DoubleClick for Publishers SDK. The classes we use are PublisherAdRequest and PublisherAdView.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdView

One ad had an error last week which was forcing the ad to reload every second. This was a desaster because the app was loading tons of MB in the background with no use.

This happened while the app was in the background. Of course, loading the ad started in foreground.

We call adView.pause() in the MainActivity onPause() method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

But still the ad was able to load data forever in the background (like tons of MB).

As our app does not need any background data and is only performing task in the foreground I am looking for a way to disable background data for our app via the manifest file.

I couldn't find any option. Did I miss something? It would be a great feature if an app can say "Yes, we need network, but only in foreground"

If even the user can restrict any app to foreground network, the app developer itself should be able to do it too. How?

Is there any other way to ensure that a mad banner is not using too much network data?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we can really do that. I looked around as well.

As an alternative, did you try to pause the Ad when the app goes background and resume it back when it comes foreground?

The below code goes in the Activity / Fragment. The same example is illustrated in the AdMob API [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView).

```
@Override
 public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     // Resume the AdView.
     mAdView.resume();
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
     // Pause the AdView.
     mAdView.pause();

     super.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     // Destroy the AdView.
     mAdView.destroy();

     super.onDestroy();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already call adView.destroy(); and adView.pause() but we forget to call adView.resume(). I am wondering if these methods do anything if the ad can still load data after "onPause" and ist still shown when resumed without calling onResume()

Comment: And as I checked we do not use AdMob but doubleclick.PublisherAdView. I will update my question